# Creating a site column of type Choice using Powershell script gives error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, site-column

I have written a powershell script to create site columns in the site. I am able to create site columns of type text and number but when I try creating columns of type Choice I get error. The following is my code:

```
# Build a string array with the choice values separating the values at ","
                $choiceFieldChoices = @($siteColumn.Choices.Split(","))

                # Declare a new empty String collection
                 $stringColl = new-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection

                # Add the choice fields from array to the string collection
                $stringColl.AddRange($choiceFieldChoices)

                # Create a new choice field and add it to the web using overload method
                $newSiteColumn = $web.Fields.Add($name,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Choice, [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($siteColumn.Required), $false,$false, $stringColl)
                # Update the web
                $web.Update()
```

It throws an error in the $web.Fields.Add statement. The error that I get is

> Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "6".

I have tried a lot but was unable to figure out what is wrong.
Please guide.

Comment: Please post the script you use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `SPFieldCollection.Add (String, SPFieldType, Boolean, Boolean, StringCollection)` has only five arguments. Whereas, in your code you are passing 6 parameters. Try changing the code to this:

```
$newSiteColumn = $web.Fields.Add($name,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Choice, $false,$false, $stringColl)
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ms477246.aspx